# Java Xml document how to get attribute inside node

Tags: xml

I'm new in using Xml and I don't even know if the title is correct... anyway, I have a node like this:

```
 <process id="Google" isExecutable="true" name="Google">
```

If I do `getElementsByTagName("process").item(0)` it returns me the text inside the `<process>...</process>` node, but I need to get the value of the `id` attribute(?) that in this case is "Google"... how do I get it? What's the method to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there are many different APIs for processing XML in Java. The fact that you're using `getElementsByTagName()` suggests you're using DOM, which is the oldest and the worst-designed, though it's also the most popular because it's built into the JDK rather than requiring a third-party library (the best XML tools come from third parties). If you're new to the game, without legacy constraints, I'd suggest using something more modern like JDOM2 or XOM.

Secondly, `getElementsByTagName()` doesn't return the text inside the element, it returns the element node. Given the element node, you can simply use the getAttribute() method to get the value of the "id" attribute.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Surely I'm doing something stupid, but if I do `doc.getELementsByTagName()` then the method `getAttribute()` does not exist

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList`; you can get the individual nodes using `NodeList.item(i)` which returns a `Node`, which you can cast to an `Element`. You need to make yourself familiar with the Javadoc specs.